# Nested If Else statement in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Nested if else statement that checks enum states

```
if ( status == enum.value1) 
{
    //Call some function 1 
}
else if ( status == enum.value2) 
{
    //call some function 2
}
else if ( status == enum.valu3 ) 
{
   call some function 3. 
}
else if ( status == enum.valu3  || status == enum.valu10) 
{
   call some function 4. 
}
```

How could i refactor/simplify this? I do not want to use a swicth case.

Comment: But **why** don't you want to use a switch case? This is exactly what you want.

Comment: I suppose that you can make `status` a base class of some sort, and use polymorphism

Comment: The emphasize sharclouds comment: But why don't you want to use a switch case? This is exactly what you want! :)

Comment: I'm with @sharpcloud - using a `switch` is what you *want* here. Also, using `status = enum.valueX` instead of `status == enum.valueX` will give you unwanted results...

Comment: else if ( status = enum.valu3  && status = enum.valu10) ??

Comment: hoe status will be equal to two enum values

Comment: How can one value be equal to two different other ones?

Comment: @Satpal @Corak: `enum Foo {a=0, b=0}`

Comment: @DominicKexel - "different". With `enum Foo {a=0, b=0}` a `case Foo.a` will suffice. If `a != b` then `status == a && status == b` will always be false.

Comment: @DominicKexel: While technically true, why would anyone need to check for both if they're supposed to be the same? I can't see why one would alter the exact enum values often enough to justify having such a check.

Comment: If this is C# like you tagged it, `=` is the assignment operator. Don't you mean `==`?

Comment: One reason not to use a switch statement, is every time the enum values change, you have to change the class...

Comment: @KristianHellang - true, but if you change the enum, you will always need to change *something* if you want to work with those other values.

Comment: @corak *How can one value be equal to two different other ones?* Never, obviously (besides operator overloading, of course). Since the OP wants to compare `status` with an enum, I just showed that you can in fact create an enum where two or more values of that enum are equal. Why anybody actually wants to do this? No idea.

Comment: @KristianHellang When you make a change, it means you want to make a change, and you therefore need to make a change. The idea isn't about preventing changes, it is about making them easier and nicer - your solution is worse than OP's current code by much, if you consider expandability.

Comment: (After the edit) Okay, now `||` makes a lot more sense. And `switch` makes that even easier, because you can have lots of different `case`s with one body. Also written like this, function 4 will still only be called if `status == enum.valu10`, because the case `status == valu3` is already handled.

Comment: @Corak He could have both cases with same body, and only run the only-case-value3 code in an if statement, and then running the code that is shared among the `value3` and `value4` cases. `switch (x) { case a: break; case b: case c: if (b) { mbox("b"); } mbox("c"); break; }`

Answer (score 9):

Try a Dictionary. Fill it up with delegates:

```
Dictionary<YourEnum, Action> dict = new Dictionary<YourEnum, Action>();
dict.Add(YourEnum.value1, MyMethod1);
dict.Add(YourEnum.value2, MyMethod2);
//etc.
```

And then return them plus invoke them when needed:

```
dict[myEnumValue]();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a large amount of options, to the point where several ifs or a switch statement is inconvenient, you could create a Dictionary with the enum type as the key and a delegate as the value.

Comment: Combine with Martin's answer, which includes code. Yours show when it should be used.

Answer (score -2):

There is no way (as far as I know) to simplify your code pattern. Which seems no problem, because it's already extremely simple.